# BeautifulSoup - extracting text from multiple span elements w/o classes

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So that's how HTML looks:

```
<p class="details">
<span>detail1</span>
<span class="number">1</span>
<span>detail2</span>
<span>detail3</span>
</p>
```

I need to extract detail2 & detail3.

But with this piece of code I only get detail1.

```
info = data.find("p", class_ = "details").span.text
```

How do I extract the needed items?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all `<span>`s and do normal indexing:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<p class="details">
<span>detail1</span>
<span class="number">1</span>
<span>detail2</span>
<span>detail3</span>
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

spans = soup.find("p", class_="details").find_all("span")

for s in spans[-2:]:
    print(s.text)
```

Prints:

```
detail2
detail3
```

---

Or CSS selectors:

```py
spans = soup.select(".details span:nth-last-of-type(-n+2)")

for s in spans:
    print(s.text)
```

Prints:

```
detail2
detail3
```

Comment: Thank you! I will proceed with this option. Have a great day ahead!

Answer (score 1):

Select your elements more specific in your case all sibling `<span>` of `<span>` with `class` number:

```
soup.select('span.number ~ span')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<p class="details">
<span>detail1</span>
<span class="number">1</span>
<span>detail2</span>
<span>detail3</span>
</p>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[t.text for t in soup.select('span.number ~ span')]
```

##### Output

```
['detail2', 'detail3']
```